# How to reformat the date text in each individual box of a column?

Tags: python, excel, powerquery

I currently converted a list of roughly 1200 items (1200 rows) and a problem arised when i looked at the date of each individual item and realised that the day and month was before the year which meant that ordering them by date would be useless. Is there any way I can reorder over 1200 dates so that they can be formatted correctly with me having to manually do it. Would I have to use python. I am very new to that and I don't know how to use it really.

Here's an example of what I get:
September 9 2016

And this is what i want:
2016 September 9

I am also using the microsoft excel if anyone was asking.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please, provide details of what you tried so far. I assume you need to review [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) Python built-in library to work with dates.

Comment: The type of the column should be "Date", then sorting will work fine. Don't use "Text" type for Date or Date/Time fields...

Answer (score 0):

it must be date format.

you can split date parts in other cells and re-merge them in preferred format...

Answer (score 0):

This answer is with power query perspective.

Considering that your column is a date Data type, Please follow the below:

Split the **DATE** in to year,MonthName,Day like below and finally merge it

[image]